# Android 13 read arbitrary files from external sd card

Tags: android

In Android 13 and later, how do I read arbitrary files from arbitrary locations on the external SD card? What permissions do I need? How do I write arbitrary files to arbitrary locations on the SD card?

For example how would I write an app which lists all files in a folder and allows me to view and open them?

I'm confused by the various different things I read as many answers pertain to older versions of Android, and all I see is things about `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` and `READ_MEDIA_*`. For example how do I read a text file, or an .html file, from the Downloads folder?

Comment: Do you really mean from a removable micro-sd card?

Comment: In general if the file is not created by your app you let the user pick the file using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. No permissions needed.

Comment: `how would I write an app which lists all files in a folder ` If the folder contains images and you obtained READ_MEDIA_IMAGES then you can list them in the classic way.

Comment: When not media let the user pick the folder using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: If I have a folder, copied onto the SD card from a PC, containing .png files, .ogg files, and plain text files, with the convention that if there are e.g. myfile.ogg and myfile.png and myfile.txt in the same folder, then these are considered related, how do I do that? Or for example if I wanted to form a list of all .txt files recursively contained in a particular folder on the microsd card?

Comment: yes, removable micro-sd card.

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select the folder. You can then list all files and subfolders.

Comment: Method 2: Using your pc to copy a folder to the micro-sd card copy it to getExternalFilesDirs()[1]. Your app then has access to that app specific directory in the classic way without user interaction.